# Numerical Computation of Chapman-Kolmogorov Condition for a Dataset

Tags: probability, statistics, numerical-methods, markov-chains, time-series

Good day every one, I am trying to solve a particular problem relating to probabilities:

I have a time series dataset, where the price at time $t_i$ can be given as $x(t_i)$

We can then define a returns time series where $r_i = \ln[x(t_{i+1})/x(t_i)]$

I now want to find some timescale $t_M$ for which the returns could be viewed as a Markov process. For this, we require the Chapman-Kolmogorov (CM) equation
$$p(r_2, t_2|r_1, t_1) = \int dr' p(r_2, t_2|r', t')p(r', t'|r_1, t_1) $$
to hold where p represents the usual conditional probability which can be given as

$$p(r_i, t_i|r_j, t_j) = \frac{p(r_i, t_i;r_j, t_j) }{p(r_j, t_j) } $$

We can  reformulate the CM equation as  the value
$$S= |(p(r_2, t_2|r_1, t_1)- \int dr' p(r_2, t_2|r', t')p(r', t'|r_1, t_1) |$$

For some given  $r_1$ and $r_2$ in terms of $t'-t_1$ for example. We then expect $t_M = t'-t_1$ for a value of $t'-t_1$ where S vanishes or reaches its minimum.

From what I have read, this value S, the CM conditions and subsequently the conditional probabilities can be computed numerically. So much so, that all the papers I have read make it seem like it a trivial matter. But I cannot find a way to do it.

Does anyone know how to compute such values numerically from a given dataset?

Thank you for your help
.